# Get a textbox to accept only characters in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ascii, keypress

I'm creating a simple application in Vb.net where I need to perform certain validations. So I want a name textbox to accept only characters from a-z and A-Z for example.

For this I wrote the following code:

```
   Private Sub txtname_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox5.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) > 65 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) < 90 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 96 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) < 122 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But somehow it is not allowing me to enter characters. When I try to enter any character it does nothing.

What causes this problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alternatively, you can do something like this,

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) _
                              Handles txtName.KeyPress

    If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        Dim allowedChars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        If Not allowedChars.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString.ToLower) Then
            e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

or if you still want the `ASCII` way, try this,

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtName.KeyPress

    If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        If Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 97 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 122) Or (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 65 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 90)) Then
            e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

both will behave the same.

Comment: But even the code wich i wrote shd work .... do u think there issum prob wid the code ??

Comment: @EqEdi your code will not work because your conditions are messed up, causing the compiler to confuse :D

Comment: @JohnWoo Nice solution. Adapted and linked on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151574/automatically-remove-not-authorized-character-on-regular-expressions-just-after/

Comment: if this work with numeric ?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub txtname_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox5.KeyPress

    If AscW(e.KeyChar) > 64 And AscW(e.KeyChar) < 91 Or AscW(e.KeyChar) > 96 And AscW(e.KeyChar) < 123 Or AscW(e.KeyChar) = 8 Then 
    Else
        e.KeyChar = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a more abstract approach, but still effective nonetheless. It's straightforward and can just be added to the `TextChanged` event. You can use it with multiple textboxes by adding their handles to the sub and using a `DirectCast()`.

```
Dim allowed As String = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
        For Each c As Char In TextBox.Text
            If allowed.Contains(c) = False Then
                TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text.Remove(TextBox.SelectionStart - 1, 1)
                TextBox.Select(TextBox.Text.Count, 0)
            End If
        Next
```

**Summary:** If an invalid character is entered, it will immediately be deleted (most of the time the character won't be visible long enough for the user to notice).

Answer (score 0):

Am using below code to accept only letters, "-" or "'" when user is entering a person name (maybe it is simple and easier):

```
Private Sub txtEName1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtEName1.KeyPress
    If Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = vbBack Or e.KeyChar = "-" Or e.KeyChar = "'" Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I allowed the backspace in order to allow the user to remove letters in case of mistakes

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub txtStudentName_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtStudentName.KeyPress

  If Not Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Delete) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) And Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Space) Then

      e.Handled = True

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Generally, don't put code in comments. [Edit] your answer instead, and make sure you use code block formatting for readability.