# Automatically remove not authorized character on Regular Expressions just after being typed

Tags: vb.net

I'm using this code

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyTextBox.KeyPress

    If Not Regex.Match(MyTextBox.Text, "^[a-z /s ']*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success Then
        MyTextBox.Text = MyTextBox.Text.Remove(MyTextBox.SelectionStart - 1, 1)
        MyTextBox.Select(MyTextBox.Text.Count, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```

so the user can only add letters, space and apostrophe

The code works if the user digit

> somethin8g

the number 8 is removed

But if the user just digit

> somethin8

the number 8 is visible until the user press another key, and even worst, if the user press the "SAVE" button the info is accepted even with the number 8

Is there a better way to automatically remove not authorized character on Regular Expressions just after being typed?

Comment: Set `e.Handled` to true to prevent the current key press from being handled. Do *not* manipulate the text currently in the textbox!

Comment: It's not working or I don´t understand the way. Using e.Handled = True inside the if instead of the text manipulation I still can digit one number and the number stay on the textbox. Also I added code like If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.ChrW(Keys.Back) Then so I can press backspace to delete

Comment: The `if` statement should be checking to see if the user typed a digit. If they did, set `e.Handled` to true to ignore the key press. Something like: `If (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) Then e.Handled = true`. You should not be manipulating the text inside of the control, and a regex is working way too hard for a simple problem.

Comment: Thanks to your guide I found and posted a solution more adaptable to any situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic solution adaptable to any situation (Just changing the allowedChars string)

No regular expression needed

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) _
                          Handles txtName.KeyPress

    If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        Dim allowedChars As String = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzáéíóúàèìòùäëïöüâêîôû '"
        If Not allowedChars.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString.ToLower) Then
            e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Adapted from the answer of Jhon Woo on [Get a textbox to accept only characters in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633780/get-a-textbox-to-accept-only-characters-in-vb-net)